# BCGcode128 Barcode with custom text or include price

Tags: php, image, barcode, inventory-management

I am new using this class BCGcode128
I want to display the item name and price including the item code on the output image.

**This is my code**

```
require('class/BCGFont.php');
require('class/BCGColor.php');
require('class/BCGDrawing.php'); 
include('class/BCGcode128.barcode.php'); 
$font =& new BCGFont('./class/font/Arial.ttf', 18);
$color_black =& new BCGColor(0, 0, 0);
$color_white =& new BCGColor(255, 255, 255); 
$code =& new BCGcode128();
$code->setScale(3);
$code->setThickness(30);
$code->setForegroundColor($color_black);
$code->setBackgroundColor($color_white);
$code->setFont($font);
$code->parse($_GET['i']);
$drawing =& new BCGDrawing('', $color_white);
$drawing->setBarcode($code);
$drawing->draw();
header('Content-Type: image/png');
$drawing->finish($drawing->IMG_FORMAT_PNG);
```

How can I display the price and item name including the item code on the output image?

Thank you in advance